# Find the minimum values for each subarray and return the maximum of these minima

Tags: python

I am trying to find the minimum values for each subarray of size x in array arr, return an integer denoting the maximum of these minima.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def segment(x, arr): 
    n = len(arr) 
    if (n < x): 
        return -1
    res = 0
    for i in range(x): 
        res += arr[i] 
    curr_sum = res 
    for i in range(x, n): 
        curr_sum += arr[i] - arr[i-x] 
        res = max(res, curr_sum) 
    return res
```

```
segment(2,[8,2,4])
```

```
Output = 10
```

```
Expected output = 2
```

Can someone help me with what I'm missing? I guess my code is finding the maximum sum instead of maximum value of the minimum subarrays.

It works perfectly when size `x = 1`.

Thanks.

Comment: The question doesn't mention sums, why does the code calculate a max sum?

Comment: That's why I need help. I'm taking the wrong approach. and I can't even think straight

Comment: Did you write that code? I'm honestly puzzled. That's not a beginner's code and I'd think someone able to write that code would know that it's solving a different problem and would know how to solve your problem...

Comment: No I didn't all by myself. I saw how this works for maximum sum, so I'm trying to see how to solve it for max of minimum subarray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure about the wording of your question. I'm assuming you mean each continuous subarray of length `x` in `arr`.

So in the example, `arr = [8,2,4]` so you have subarrays `[8,2]` and `[2,4]`. The min of each subarray is 2, and the max is therefore 2.

```py
def segment(x, arr): 
    n = len(arr) 
    if (n < x): 
        return -1
    segment_mins = []
    for i in range(n-x+1): 
        segment_mins.append(min(arr[i:i+x]))
    return max(segment_mins)
```

Edit: You might achieve a speedup by doing it in one line

```py
def segment(x, arr): 
    n = len(arr) 
    if (n < x): 
        return -1
    return max(min(arr[i:i+x]) for i in range(n-x+1))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want, but I'm still getting an error that says... ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence...

Comment: Sorry, just fixed a bug. Should be `n-x+1` in the range

Comment: Thanks. is there any way I can improve the time complexity of my code? It says: Your code did not execute within the time limits... I'm trying out some leetcode problems. Thanks

Comment: @Eniola If it's from LeetCode or so then it helps to include the link in the question. Lets us see more details and lets us try it there ourselves.

Comment: I just edited my answer to include a one-line expression that might speed it up. This won't reduce the complexity of the code, but should speed it up.

Comment: @Eniola Which problem at LeetCode is it? I'd be surprised if the oneliner were noticeably faster.